# Using container view with Xamarin and MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

[image: Storyboard]

I am trying to use a Container View within a View Controller (Free Form View) to reuse some components that are common for two views. So far I have a View Controller (Free Form View) with a Ui View and a Container View. Upon opening up the Free Form View, Container View should contain Free Form Purchase View, but when pressing the blue Button, that View should be replaced with the View last View Controller. I have a similar setup for Android where I use Fragments.

I am looking for the best way to navigate between the controllers. I use MVVMCross throughout the application, but I am open to other suggestions that does not involve MVVMCross.

Comment: do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your own controller which handles swapping of Views in Container View through custom Segue implementation.

You can find detailed step how to do this from Richard Woollcott post: [Using the ContainerView to Transition between Views - aka More Fragments in Xamarin.iOS](http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/using-the-containerview-to-transition-between-views-aka-more-fragments-in-xamarin-ios/)

Comment: the post in the link is over 4 years old. does anybody have some actual code with mvvmcross 7.x?